# DropDownListFor selected value not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

So I have this in my view(I have broken it out into a foreach so I could debug it properly). And according to the objects that are created it looks good. I get 1 item that has the selected true.

```
@{
    var useritems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var si in Model.UserList)
    {
        if (Model.CurrentUser.Id.Equals(si.Id))
        {
            useritems.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = si.Username, Value = si.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }); 
        }
        else
        {
            useritems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = si.Username, Value = si.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do  here is check for the current(logged on) user and set the select default to him/her.

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Creator, useritems, new { id = "CreatorDDL", })
```

This does not however set any of the objects in useritems to selected. Even tho in the debugger it shows that 1 item has selected: true

Somehow it just shows the first item in the list.
Any ideas? or am I just tired and missing something really easy?

Comment: what is in `model.Creator`? Maby you just set selected `Id` to it?

Comment: Model.Creator is just an int  property in my model for this view

Comment: Have you try to set it? i mean `model.Creator = Model.CurrentUser.Id`

Comment: Thank you @teovankot

You made me realize what I was doing wrong. I had forgotten to set any value to the creator as you said!

Comment: There is no point setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` if you binding to a property. And it can be as simple as `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Creator, new SelectList(Model.UserList, "id", "Username"))` and remove all the code in your first snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `model.Creator` value in addition to `Selected` in `SelectList`.

```
model.Creator = Model.CurrentUser.Id;
```

It's better to do such things in your `Controller`, not in your `View`.

Comment: Yes I moved all the logic/code inte the controlle->repository. Thanks again